# make: No rule to make target 'obj/AudioHandler.o', needed by '../build/libgameengine.a'. Stop

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, sdl

I've looked at several similar posts reporting this error however, the majority seem to be related to running make in a different folder than that of the source files. In my case, the cpp files are in the same folder as my makefile from which I am running the make command. It seems my rule cannot locate 'AudioHandler.cpp' despite it being in the same folder as the makefile itself. I assume there is an error with a path somewhere, as this file is suspiciously the first one in the list! What am I doing wrong?

```
# compiler to use
CXX = g++

# header folder
IDIR = ../include

# compile flags
CXXFLAGS = -I$(IDIR) -Wall -std=c++0x `sdl2-config --cflags` `sdl2-config --libs` -lSDL_mixer

# output folder
ODIR = obj

# build folder
BDIR = ../build

# engine dependencies
_DEPS = AudioHandler.hpp Callback.hpp Entity.hpp Font.hpp Game.h GameMap.hpp GameMath.h InputHandler.hpp MapHandler.hpp Matrix3x3.hpp Matrix4x4.hpp Palette.hpp ScreenHandler.hpp Structs.h System.hpp Ticker.hpp Utilities.hpp Vec2.hpp Vec3d.hpp ZX_Palette.hpp Scene.h UpdateComponent.hpp vec2.hpp
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

# engine cpp directory
_OBJ = AudioHandler.o Callback.o Entity.o Font.o Game.o GameMap.o InputHandler.o MapHandler.o Matrix4x4.o Palette.o ScreenHandler.o System.o Ticker.o Utilities.o Vec2.o Vec3d.o ZX_Palette.o vec2.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

$(ODIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS)

$(BDIR)/libgameengine.a: $(OBJ)
    ar rcs $@ $^
```

Comment: Please put the command you typed and the error you got into the question (formatted).  Putting it into the question subject is OK but much harder to read.

Comment: The only way you can be getting this error is if either (a) the `AudioHandler.cpp` file doesn't exist, or else (b) one or more of the header files in `$(DEPS)` doesn't exist.  To know what make is unable to find, run `make -d` and look for what file it can't build.

Comment: Please show the full build log and directory tree listing.

Comment: @MadScientist You were correct, I had some discrepancies between my headers and DEPS